# can't change React js modal overlay opacity

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a react JS app , and I'm using `react-modal` package . I don't know how to make the outside part of the Modal ,when it is opened, completely transparent .
This is the props that I pass it to the Modal :

```js
<Modal
  onRequestClose={() => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });
  }}
  isOpen={modalIsOpen}
  className="Modal"
></Modal>
```

This is the CSS code :

```css
.Modal {
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid #040408;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  width: 20.8%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  outline: none;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}
```

And this is the result that I get :
[image: A screen shot]

I want my modal to look just like a popup.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean background of model to be transparent? like the grey part of picture? in this case you should put it inside another div.

```js
<div className='transparent'><Modal/></div>
```

Otherwise I don't understand the question.

Maybe you want to make the div fixed and max size, so it cover all the screen.

Comment: I don't want the color of the part that is outside the Modal to change when the modal is opened , the originial color is black

Comment: so you want to make border transparent? i still dont get which part you want to change